# I want to create dynamic cronjob file in php

Tags: php

I am working in php and i have some requirements where i have to call xyz.php when required. But this file can not call in browser because i have to do some process like email and sms. so i need to call this file as cronjob. But i dont want to set cronjob from cpanel/hosting panel. Because i have to run this xyz.php instant when required. And need to call only for one time.

At present i have set this file in cpanel but it only calls at specified time. I have some more process and so xyz.php may take time to complete in backend. So i want that xyz.php file should call instant dynamically in cronjob when required and also it should be run only one time.

How to do this in php ? Is it possible ?

Comment: `require_once('xyz.php')` ????

Comment: Make it an `at` or `batch` job then.

Comment: require_once() is not a correct answer. Because i need to run file only in cronjob. I dont want to run file in browser because it will take more time and we dont want to wait till process complete.

Comment: Is there any solution using exec() function ? I means is there any way where we can create cronjob file using command line into any php function ?

Comment: Is any any php professional who can solve this issue ?